# Give an incentive for tag edits?

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, badge-request

The badges for editing posts explicitly exclude tag edits. I understand why - they are supposed to reward substantial edits.

At the same time, tags are useful, necessary, for how Stack Exchange works: they are needed so people can find relevant questions, and so people can be notified there's a question they might be able to answer. So, it follows that someone who spends time correcting tags on questions does a service to the community.

So could there perhaps be some separate badge for editing tags? "Edited tags on 250 questions - Silver, Edited tags on 1000 questions - Gold", or something like that?

Answer (score 6):

Tagging is important, but mass tagging or retagging can bring noise in the active questions list that some users will not like, unlike edits that are viewed more valuable by the community.

As such I don’t think it would be a good idea to give a badge for that. As it’s an activity that can be seen bad or good depending on the person that sees those active questions.

I would more reward tag description edit, or such work that not a lot of users do.

Answer (score -4):

If nothing else, tags are probably the *last* thing in a post that needs to be edited.  Getting the "right" tags only means that the right audience is paying attention to the question, and having the wrong tags *might* mean that the wrong audience is looking at the question.

There are far, far, *far* more substantial things to improve in a post, such as grammar, word flow and sentence structure which merit reward.  Making sure your question is tagged with Java instead of Java and C is lower down the priority chain.

Comment: Lower priority - sure. Figured I reflected that with how I suggested 250 tag edits for a silver badge, compared to 80 substantial edits for the "Strunk and White" badge. Mind you, I come from [writing.se]. Because the field is not as cut-and-dried as software engineering, sometimes *all* tags on a question need to be changed, and very often you'd see new users only using the most all-encompassing tags like "fiction", no more specific tags at all. This of course affects how I see the issue.

Comment: Having the wrong tags, or missing certain kinds of tags, makes a huge number of questions in a number of SE sites totally unanswerable. Calling them the last thing that needs to be edited, and then describing "word flow" as substantial, does not reflect the experience or needs or knowledge of a significant number of users and sites.